# Passing Values with ajax/jQuery from HTML Inputforms to PHP to MySQL in XAMPP Environment

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, xampp

I set up the whole environment with XAMPP apache and mysql is running. I developed a very similar code for another application i started to program, where it was functioning successfully.

Database table name = scm:

- testID (AUTO_INCREMENT; int(11); PRIMARYKEY)
- firstname (int)
- lastname (int)

What I tested so far:

- I can collect the values of the input fields over the browsers JS Console
- I can access the PHP file over the browser which will create a new DB entry
- the function post() is running without an error

Still if I run the function nothing gets written into the DB. What am I missing?

The response I get after firing the function post() is:

```
post();
undefined
```

Furthermore, I got the alert "good" so the AJAX function does work somehow.

How can i get further information about what is happening in the background?

Folderstructure in XAMPP:

htdocs:

`scm
    index.html
    insert.php
    js
        script.js
    css
        style.css`

Index Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>The Fresh Connection DataBase</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <h2>Supply Chain</h2>
    <input id="ssci" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="settingsSupplyChainId">
    <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">Component</div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Safety Stock</div>
            <input id="sspack" class="form-control" type="text" min="0" max="9" placeholder="Pack">
            <input id="sspet" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="PET">
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Lot Size</div>
            <input id="lspack" class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Pack">
            <input id="lspet" class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="PET">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">Product</div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Production Interval</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Safety Stock</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="post()" id="btnPost" type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Post</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
function post(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        url: "insert.php",
        data: {
            firstname: $("#sspack").val(),
            lastname: $("#sspet").val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert("good");
        },
        error: function(data) {
        alert("Fehler: "+data.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

According to the recommendations in the comments i redone my insert.php. It works fine when i run the insert.php in the browser but when i try to pass the values from ajax to php nothing happens. There is no entry in the DB but the ajax runs the success function

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "scm";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO test (testID, firstname, lastname) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("iii", $testID, $firstname, $lastname);

// set parameters and execute
$testID = "";
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$stmt->execute();


echo "New records created successfully";

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: So what debugging have you done?  What is the response of the ajax request? Also, before you even go any further, you should _really_ rewrite this to use bound parameters.

Comment: you can remove `dataType: "text"` it wont do anything , also if you can share with us your ajax respanse we will be able to help you

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, use prepared statements instead.

Comment: `<script src="js/script.js"></script>` Verify that this path is correct?

Comment: path is correct. I can run test commands in the script like function test(){ alert("listening");}

Comment: I updated my solution above to react to your comments about using bound parameters. Is this now preventing me from SQL injections? Unfortunately i even get more error messages than before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

- Change the Browser to Google Chrome because Firefox was not properly deleting its cache
- simplify the script.js by removing (for now) unnecessary steps
- completely overthink insert.php

script.js

```
function post(){

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'insert.php',
        data: { firstname: $('#sspack').val(), lastname: $('#sspet').val() },
        success: function(response) {

        }
    });
}
```

insert.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "scm";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO test (testID, firstname, lastname) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("iii", $testID, $firstname, $lastname);

// set parameters and execute
$testID = '';
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$stmt->execute();


echo "New records created successfully";

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

This solution covers the transfer from an HTML input field over ajax to PHP which stores the final value into the MySQL DB.

One question for all the very experienced programmers out there. Is this now safe against MySQL Inception or did it at least made it a bit harder to crack the DB?